# Finding intersection points of line paths

Tags: algorithm, geometry, intersection, bezier, line-segment

I have two Bezier curves which share an end point. Each of these curves has an "extension" on both the left and right sides, similar to the edges of a road. The extensions are made of line segments that approximate the Bezier curve.

I want to find the closest intersection point of these paths to the shared end point of the bezier curves.

[Here is a diagram I've drawn of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gt2Ps.png)

Each line path has over 100 vertices, so intersecting each line and keeping the closest intersection point can become very slow, given that this must run in real-time.

I've run a bounding sphere intersection test on the lines before checking for an intersection point to speed things up a little, but it's still not quick enough. My next approach would be to use some sort of quadtree structure.

I've looked up the [Bentley-Ottmann algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bentley%E2%80%93Ottmann_algorithm) but it seems to deal with finding all intersections in one set of lines, which isn't what I need. I've also looked up Bezier curve intersection algorithms but they seem to require subdivision into line segments, which I already have.

Are there any useful algorithms for this problem, or perhaps any ideas on how it might be optimised?

Comment: Why the closest intersection point and not the only one? Is there a possibility that A and B meet on more than one intersection point?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11479664/find-the-intersections-of-a-pair-of-quadcurve2ds

Answer (score 0):

Given two curves A and B with extension widths Aw and Bw. Find the point A' which is the distance Bw along A from the shared node N. Find the point B' which is likewise the distance Aw along B from the shared node N. Now, given the points N, A' and B', find the fourth point N' which forms a parallelogram with the other three nodes. This point N' is the intersection.

Comment: Can you support your idea with a mathematical demonstration? It was true if A and B were arcs of different radiuses, but since they're bezier-curves I don't think that parallelogram works.